# Why is the All-In-Sustaining cost for mining gold so high relative to silver?

Tags: mining-engineering

The All In Sustaining Cost for mining an ounce of gold at the moment is around \$1,000 ; i.e. if gold mines sold gold at around \$1,000 an ounce they would make neither a profit or a loss. The equivalent cost for mining silver is \$10 an ounce. Silver is about 20 times more common than gold in the Earth's crust and from what I can tell the physical mining and refining process for the two metals is basically very similar so naively I would expect it would cost about 20 times as much to mine the same weight of gold as of silver. However the true figure is 100 times as much.

Does anyone who has experience in this area know why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider “common” v “accessible”...

Comment: Do you have references for the differences in mining costs? Underground mining costs are higher than open pit mining costs. Are you comparing like with like? Gold is usually mined from deposits that mostly contain gold, whereas silver is usually mined as a by-product associated with other metals such as lead-zinc-silver, or polymetallics such as copper-zinc-lead-silver & maybe minor gold credits. With the polymetallics it is possible the other metals are being assignment more of the costs because of the relative amounts of each metal mined from the mine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Minerals that are more concentrated are cheaper to extract.  In general.  If you think about a 40 ppm ore body versus a 2 ppm ore body, to get the same amount out of each, you have to process (mine, crush, refine) 20 times as much rock.  That costs money.  [This can be even more extreme if you consider yield--it is generally easier to get higher percentage extraction in a high grade ore than a low grade one...consider if your leach process has a minimum of say 0.5 ppm heading to tails...that impacts you more with 2 ppm start than with 40.]

   There will be some differences Au vs Ag based on the chemistry--I think especially with competition with copper in adsorption/refining.  So I'm not sure which is cheaper if equal grades (and similar host rock, but that's not given either) to extract.  But just the sheer difference in concentration makes a vast difference in costs which drives up the cost of gold production.
2. Price has allowed a lot of gold mining to occur that would not if prices were lowered. You can process lower grade ores and use more extreme practices.  I just got done with several months of operations consulting at a complicated gold processing plant.  Basically throughput was main driver, yield was second (assuming grade fixed by geology).  Cost was for all practical purposes irrelevant.

   Sure they would do a calculation for any new project or change in operations.  But pretty much anything that would increase gold ounces per year was going to carry its costs.  But that works a lot better at $2000/oz vs. at $500.  This leads to industry costs on overage increasing.  The industry has a long history with this--if/when prices crash, you will see cost cutting that is dramatic.

P.s.  It is common that gold and silver are found/extracted in similar bodies.  So a gold mine/plant will have some silver as a byproduct.  Sometimes this even justifies the economics for a marginal plant.  However, in general, you can look at the production of these two metals relatively independently.  (Copper may also be a recoverable byproduct in a gold mine, depends on the concentration...kind of a nuisance for gold processing generally but if enough of it, you can justify separating it and selling it, versus letting it go to tails.)

Comment: Under current mineral valuations, a 40 ppm Au underground body or open pit body will be profitable. A 2 ppm Au open pit body may be profitable, but an underground one will not - so no underground project. A small scale low grade operation may be unprofitable, whereas a large scale one might be. The key economic driver is the cost per tonne. Usually larger mines & larger processing plants have a lower cost per tonne than smaller mines or processing plants.

Comment: Cu in a predominantly Au body can be a project killer. If the body is to be processed by a well established CIP or CIL plant with no Cu processing capabilities, the amount of Cu above a certain grade make the mineral deposit uneconomic & kill the mine.

Answer (score 0):

Silver is commonly a byproduct of lead and zinc mining, and to a much lesser extent, copper. Therefore, the economics of silver mining are determined largely by the demand supply balance of zinc and lead in the world.